# Running R from CD-ROM

Tags: r

Can R be run from a CD-ROM drive?  The computer is a stand-alone (no network or Internet connection) and I can't install anything on it, nor can I use a flash drive.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by "can't install"?

You don't need to install R, you can just run it from a folder copied from somewhere else. If you have hard disk storage on the PC then you can copy `C:\Program Files\R` from one machine onto a CD-ROM, then take the CD-ROM to the cripplebox, copy it to wherever you store your files and run it from there. Worst case scenario is you have to change the R_HOME environment variable. Works for Linux and Windows (you didnt say what OS you are on).

...unless your sysadmins have disabled executable permissions for your hard disk storage. Which is a real BOFH thing to do.

...but if they've done that I'd also suspect they've disabled executables from CD-ROM too.

...and if you don't have any writable hard disk storage, how the heck are you going to do any analysis?

...the real fix may be to kick the sysadmins until you tell them you can't do your job without R installed on the machine.

Comment: That advice ain't gonna work without a major helping of pixiedust.  Anyway, it's not unusual for "secure areas" to ban any memory media that's writable, and to have a (stupid, pointless) ban on installing executables.  Hence the CD-ROM limit.

Comment: Yet leave the loophole of mounting CD-ROMs executable? Let's wait for the OP to give us some clues. Heck, if you can stick a CD-ROM in the machine you can break the damn box open and install Linux on it.

Answer (score 1):

You may have trouble with packages, but otherwise, the instructions for [installing R on a USB key](http://personal.bgsu.edu/~mrizzo/Rmisc/usbR.htm) should be pertinent.

Comment: A USB drive is writeable whereas the CD-ROM is not.  The question is whether or not `R` needs to write to any of the config files in its own directory.  Assuming it does not, then you still need to be sure to burn the appropriate set of path names and locations for `.Rdata`, `Rhistory`, etc. into the `.Rprofile.site` file on the CDROM.   Or play some tricks with the Properties of the R-link file on your C:drive.